# Adding UIWebView to second (not first) Storyboard view controller

Tags: uiwebview, storyboard, viewcontroller, xcode4.6.3

Getting started with xCode 4.6.3 and I'm running into a hiccup.

I've built a simple app using the UIWebView to display a local HTML file and it's contents.  I used that to debug any issues with the HTML and/or image displays and I'm all set.

Now I need to recreate that within a larger project I've built with storyboards for all my navigations between multiple view controllers.  My issue comes when I'm trying to control-click drag from the WebView into the ViewController.h code below the @interface like many tutorials show, and that worked fine within my smaller single view controller app.  It won't do it.  I know I'm missing something obvious here.  Am I going to have the set up these screens (I have multiple ones to do this same way) as separate xib files and add them into my main project?

Thanks for any help and clarification.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called for example myWebViewController and in Interface builder add a UIWebView to it. The control+drag to the header file will work.
Every time you want a UIViewController that has a browser in it, define its class as myWebViewController in Interface Builder.
Try not to repeat code. If you see UIViewControllers or any other UIView...that do the same thing, you can group them into a class that you use over and over.